# Is it unprofessional to have alternative editors / programming tools installed on a work machine?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry

I work as an Intermediate software developer for a company that primarily uses the Microsoft Stack. When a new employee starts they are given a virtual machine which has there standard tooling installed:

- Visual Studio + Resharper
- Sql Developer
- Slack
- SVN
- Etc

Now, while i have no problems with these tools and revert to them for pair programming i prefer to use other tools most of the time and as such I've installed:

- Emacs
- Vim (Yes i know i installed both, lets move on)
- Python
- Ruby
- Racket

Recently an IT guy (manager?) scanned my machine and was concerned that i installed these applications, he seems to think it indicates I'm a security threat. He asked me to explain why i used this and also informed my boss (The Software Development Director). There is no problem with us installing our own applications like Spotify, Jing, Vlc, etc. So he seems to think these programs / languages are somehow related to hackers/ing.

Luckily my Boss knew that i like to use these tools and he had no problem with them however i still needed to explain why i use them to the IT guy and he seems to want me to uninstall them, although he hasn't said this.

Finally, My question is: Is it unprofessional of me to install these tools given that no one else uses them here and that i was given different tools to work with? Also: should i uninstall them, or perhaps document why/how i use them?

Comment: I'd like to know what you intend to do with projects written on platforms that aren't supported in your company's environment.

Comment: @WesleyLong The languages were just for scripts i used to automate parts of my own workflows. The bulk of my work is still in C#.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the opinion of an IT guy who thinks developer tools are somehow a security threat. You boss handled it, and all's well. Just move on

Comment: @Rob I would, sometimes he can get you reprimanded or sacked. He has his own role to perform.

Comment: @Kilisi If a developer were sacked for installing *extremely well known* programming tools, it's probably for the best. I'd really like to see the argument coming from this 'IT guy', saying emacs is a security concern, yet VLC and Spotify are not.

Comment: @Rob There is no need for argument, if there are protocols in place forbidding installation of such stuff, bye bye developer. In fact these tools installed are not essential to the work. I handle some very high security networks that would have sacked the dev, no questions asked. I have no idea what those tools are, if I saw them I'd give him a professional heads up to get rid of them, if he didn't I'd get him removed.

Comment: Reading your question title I was thinking "No, of course not". But then I read you use emacs and vim. This is entirely unacceptable, you will have to choose the right editor for you. Oh, and of course emacs is insane and you should chose the one and only editor worth having: vim

Comment: Did you get permission or at least inform your boss before you installed them? Then all you say to the IT guy is that you cleared all this with your boss, and it's between them and not you.

Comment: @HorusKol not explicitly although he new i use them. Explaining to the IT guy that he new definitely helped i  think.

Comment: You code in a virtual machine? 

Answer (score 13):

Unless you have a strictly controlling IT dept whose objection is based on not going through their hoops to install them it shouldn't be a general professional issue.  However you should confirm with someone (generally either in IT or your supervisor) that IT isn't going to make a big deal of it before you start installing stuff left and right.

Making an issue of it while pair programming would be problematic, but you said you're not doing that.

Unless you're asked to do so I don't see any general reason to writeup how the tools work.  IF you end up building some sort of significant labor saving infrastructure/automation with them, that should be documented.  But that would be equally the case if you built extra tooling using the standard software stack.

Answer (score 10):

**It's not *inherently* unprofessional to use whatever tools help you in your job.**

There's nothing wrong with using a tool that no one else uses, per se.  If something helps you be more productive in your work, then it is professional to use it (if allowed).

However, being able to work easily with others is a big factor to consider here.  It's possible that tools increase you *personal* productivity, but lower the *team* productivity if they put up barriers to working together.

You are obviously aware of this issue (since you revert to the standard tools for pair programming), but make sure you have fully counted the cost of your way of working.  Using a different text editor is probably no big deal, but is it really ok to use other languages like Python and Ruby?  If you are writing code that no one else understands (even for quick utility scripts and the like), that may be more of a problem.

**Company expectations and policies vary.**

There are two different issues here: installing software on your machine yourself, and using software that is different from the team's standard.  On both issues you will find company policies that vary from complete freedom to complete lockdown.  And even if there is no formal policy, there might be informal expectations.  Obviously you need to work within the boundaries set by your employer.

**Have a chat with your boss to clarify expectations and the way forward.**

Your boss already knows about this, which is good.  But it would be good to check with him that really knows everything you are doing, he is truly happy with your way of working, and that you are not pushing the boundary here.

If your boss has no objection to what you do and is willing to back you up, then I would not worry about the IT guy.

Comment: I didn't think about the difference between policy and expectation, Thank you. I'm going to take your advice and check with my Boss just to make sure we're on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's unprofessional to install programs without first consulting the IT dept. I'm not saying it's harmful, but anything on machines that is unknown to the IT people is a potential security concern. Quite possibly they have excellent reasons that you are unaware of.

Comment: If the IT department doesn't want you to install things, they should make it impossible to do so.

Comment: @TheMerryMisanthrope or just tell you and expect you to be adult about it? Sometimes it's done like that because they need to give you installation rights for other reasons like updates.

Comment: I´m guessing if IT told him not to do this, this question wouldn´t be here. So probably they didn´t mention it.

Comment: @Erik possibly, or possibly he doesn't remember that bit, either way my answer stands, you should clear things with IT first, it's the professional way to do things which is what the question was. It's not your machine and you're not responsible for overall security, IT is.

Comment: If that's their strategy, it's going to be on the IT department's heads when someone malicious does come along.

Comment: @TheMerryMisanthrope I think you underestimate what IT can do, I've had a network go to sea with a tsunami with no loss of data when I got them new machines. And yes it might be on their heads, they should have protocols and procedures in place to take care of it, one of which might be to discipline people who don't comply. Not saying that will happen here though.

Comment: This is very company-specific, not universally true.  Many employees (especially developers) have the freedom to install software as they see fit.

Comment: @dan1111 sure they do, but the professional thing to do is clear it, which is what I answered on, all these comments are fluff

Comment: Clearing it should be taken (I assume) as talking to them once about the overall policy? I know that IT here would be irritated if I had to ask to install every individual piece of software that I use. We have a "no one installs anything" policy at our company, but that does not extend to devs. We get a reallllly long leash, as our job sometimes requires non-standard software. IT would lose it if I were in there with "hey, I need codecompare, mind if I install it?" and "Oi, I need fiddler, you okay with that?" every time I needed something.

Comment: Any company that prevents the programmer from using his preferred tools has a broken IT policy. Ignore broken things and get your work done.

Comment: @SliderBlackrose most places give devs a long leash, some would require you to ask each time, they wouldn't lose it, it's their rules so part of their role. Others it's just a one off, others don't care at all. But it's 'professional to ask'.

Comment: @Kilisi My point was more how many times you ask: Getting permission set in place and knowing what that encompasses before hand or early on is preferred to asking for each and every piece.